# Create login form using ASP.NET Web API, stored procedure and AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

I want to create a login form using ASP.NET Web API, stored procedure and AngularJs without token based authentication and identity and ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Very admirable desire! In the meantime, you can start here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you please provide us with the solution you already tried? and maybe be more specific as to where in the process you are currently stuck by rephrasing your question for example? As of now, it is hard for us to help you.

Comment: I have a table which is created using entity framework database first approach which contains username and password. I want to create a stored procedure for login form then I want to use that stored procedure in asp.net web api and instead of using view of asp.net mvc I want to use simple html to display the result of login such as login successful or login failed. I want to connect that asp.net web api and html page using angularjs. I want simple way and not token based authentication.